# Sharing an image using the WebShare API in iOS is failing

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, web-share

I trying to use the WebShare API to share an image in iOS and Android. In Android, my code works perfectly, but in iOS, in some apps like WhatsApp doesn't share the image, it only shares the URL. In a few apps like the email, it's working. I added some code for preventing to share anything else besides the image in iOS like this:

```
let data = IS_SAFARI ? { files: [], text: '', url: '', title: '' } : { files: [], text: text, url: URL, title: TITLE };
```

But it still doesn't show the image, it only shares an URL:

```js
const URL = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/27/Map_of_Spain_1490.jpg';
const TYPE = 'image/jpeg';
const EXT = '.jpg';
const TITLE = "yourTitle";
const IS_SAFARI = /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

function webshare(text) {

    let navigator;
    navigator = window.navigator;
    let data = IS_SAFARI ? { files: [], text: '', url: '', title: '' } : { files: [], text: text, url: URL, title: TITLE };

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', URL, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = xhr.response;
        console.log(response);

        var blob = new File([response], text + EXT, { type: TYPE });
        data.files.push(blob);
        console.log(data);

        if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare(data)) {
            navigator.share(data)
            .then(function() {})
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error('Unsuccessful share ' + err);
            });
        }
        } else {
        console.error('Failed to load ' + URL + ': ' + xhr.status);
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="webshare('Map_of_Spain_1490.jpg')">Share</button>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix it. I had to remove the `url`, `text`, and `title` values from the share like this:

```js
let data = IS_SAFARI ? { files: [] } : { files: [], text: text, url: URL, title: TITLE };
```

For any mysterious reason, you cannot share **texts** and **files** on iOS at the same time. Then, if I wanted to share a text, I had to do it as a second share like this:

```js
navigator.share(data)
.then(function() {
    if (IS_SAFARI) {
        let dataText = { files: [], text: text, url: URL, title: TITLE };
        navigator.share(dataText);
    }                                
})
.catch(function(err) {
    console.error('Unsuccessful share ' + err);
});
```

It's a very odd and inconvenient bug in iOS. Hopefully, one day Apple will fix these odd bugs.

Comment: We are having an issue with iOS 16: the image can be shared (share sheet pops) but save to photos is missing since iOS 16. Do you see the same? It's like apple removed the ability to save photos this way

Comment: @xaphod have you found a fix for this? It is really annoying that videos work but images aren't.

Comment: Hi @thefinnomenon, but the images are working with my code. We have already tested it in our app.

Comment: @thefinnomenon it turned out to be an iOS/safari/webkit issue. It was fixed in a newer update of iOS I believe. I found the original github issue at one point (on apple side) but don't knwo where it is now